# Fragment and DialogFragment Lifecycle Relationship

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, android-lifecycle

I have `Fragment` "A" where I have an `ImageButton` in place. Upon clicking this button a `DialogFragment` "B" is called to the foreground where `Fragment` "A" is partially visible in the background. `DialogFragment` "B" presents the user with a list of choices. Upon clicking a specific choice `DialogFragment` "B" is dismissed via `Dismiss()` and `Fragment` "A" becomes fully visible again.

During this action I need to update the `ImageButton` on `Fragment` "A" to represent the user's choice made on `DialogFragment` "B" (basically a new image for the `ImageButton`).

Am I correct in thinking the right place to update the `ImageButton` on Fragment "A" is during `OnResume`? Does Fragment "A" go into `OnPause` while `FragmentDialog` "B" is being shown? Therefore upon returning from `DialogFragment` "B", `Fragment` "A" would trigger its `OnResume` and that's where I should make the update changes to the `ImageButton` being presented to the user?

I hope my explanation is clear. Any detailed help on where and how I should be updating the `ImageButton` would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fragment A won't go into onPause so onResume won't get called 
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

> Resumed
>   The fragment is visible in the running activity.
>
> Paused
>   Another activity is in the foreground and has focus, but the activity
>   in which this fragment lives is still visible (the foreground activity
>   is partially transparent or doesn't cover the entire screen).

Comment: Ok. So if `Fragment` A will not go into onPause, where should I update the ImageButton? I read [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) that I can implement a custom interface on the hosting activity and create a callBack so that the ImageButton can be updated. However, I'm still not sure where I would place this callBack so that the image is automatically updated upon selection of the item in `Fragment` "B", not to mention that this  solution seems extremely convoluted to solve such  a simple problem. Any ideas on how to better implement this?

Comment: @CBA110 You are right, the solution is complex for a simple problem. For some time now I have been using an event bus to avoid these interfaces as much as possible, https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus. You also have Square's Otto event bus http://square.github.io/otto/

Answer (score 2):

With the addition of ViewModels and LiveData solving this problem just got easier. Create a viewModel which both fragments reference. Put the next line in the OnCreate of the fragments. Can also be in onCreateDialog of the dialogfragment.

```
myViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(MyViewModel.class);
```

When the dialog is dismissed, call a method on myViewModel, which updates a LiveData variable:

```
dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            myViewModel.setButtonPressed(PositiveButtonPressed);
        }
    });
    dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            myViewModel.setButtonPressed(NegativeButtonPressed)
        }
    });
```

In the viewModel the method sets a MutuableLiveData variable for example to the image to be shown.

```
void SetButtonPressed(int buttonPressed){
   if (buttonPressed==positiveButtonPressed){
       imageToBeShown.setValue(image A);
   }
   else{
      imageToBeShown.setValue(image B);
   }
}
```

Set an observer to LiveData variable in onActivityCreated:

```
myViewModel.imageToBeShown().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<Image>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable Image image) {
            button.setBackground(image);
            }
        }
    });
```

Of course you can implement a getter method and keep the MutuableLiveData variable private. The observer then just obeserves the getter methode.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem when tried with Interface-Callback method but `OnResume` of `Fragment` didn't got triggered when `DialogFragment` was dismissed since we are not switching to other activity.

So here **Event Bus** made life easy. Event Bus is the easiest and best way to make communication between activities and fragments with only three step, you can see it [here](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus#eventbus-in-3-steps)

This is nothing but publish/subscribe event bus mechanism. You will get proper documentation [here](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/)

Add EventBus dependency to your gradle file - 
`compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:x.x.x'`

OR
`compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'` (Specific version)

**For the above scenario -** 
Create one custom **POJO class** for user events -

```
public class UserEvent {
    public final int userId;

    public UserEvent(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
}
```

**Subscribe** an event in `Fragment A` whenever it is posted/published from `DialogFragment` or from somewhere else -

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onUserEvent(UserEvent event) {
    // Do something with userId
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), event.userId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**Register or Unregister** your EventBus from your `Fragment A`'s lifecycle especially in `onStart` and `onStop` respectively -

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    super.onStop();
}
```

In the end, on clicking specific item, **Publish/Post** your event from `DialogFragment` -

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent(user.getId()));
```